# Diagnostics for intermittent trouble accessing Data DVDs and CD-Roms

Tags: mount, dvd, fstab

A few months ago I migrated my two PCs from Windows to Linux.
I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on one machine which I call U, and Xubuntu 14.04 LTS on the other, XU.

For months I have been able to create Data DVDs on U using Brasero, 
and immediately view the DVD created, on the same machine.
However I recently discovered that U will not generally read CD-ROMs or DVDs. I attempt to mount them with `sudo /dev/sr0 /cdrom`
but get "mount: no medium found on `/dev/sr0`

XU doesn't seem to have any trouble with CDs or DVDs.
The machine configurations are similar; both have Plextor drives, PX-716AL on U, PX-716SA on XU,
and they worked fine under Windows.

I'm not very proficient with Linux so I spent many days reading postings on related topics 
and experimenting with things, and finally discovered that there was no entry for iso9660
in `/proc/filesystems on U`, but there is on XU. The files are otherwise the same.
So I ran on U `sudo modprobe -a iso9660`
and an entry was created at the bottom of /proc/filesystems.
After lots of attempts I found that it now works sometimes! I have to wait around 40 seconds after
inserting the disc for the green light on the drive to come on, but after that I am able to mount a disk
and view it under /cdrom. Unfortunately the green light often doesn't show, I get a flashing amber one
instead and the mount fails as before with "mount: no medium found on`/dev/sr0`

It would be good if I could switch on some detailed diagnostics and see why it's behaving this way.
So can somebody please tell me how I can do that or otherwise help me work out what is going on?
I am not experienced enough with Linux to know the best way to proceed. 
There are lots of questions I am trying to answer:

Why do I have to wait 40 seconds after inserting a disk to get a green light?
Why does it often fail to show a green light then?

Is it odd that iso9660 wasn't present in `/proc/filesystems`? Might I have missed something on install
of the o-s?
Rather than load it each session what's the best way to get it there all the time - do I have to rebuild the kernel?

I like the way Windows used to respond to inserting a disk by automatically mounting it and
displaying it in File Explorer. Is that possible to replicate that in (X)Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Peter Croft

Here's `/etc/fstab` with comment lines removed:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

UUID=e394dedb-9abe-4dce-b04c-9f2a8d0f191f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

UUID=0ce0e7aa-fd6b-463a-8d3d-12499f167959 none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a problem about ISO 9660 but about
drive and/or CD/DVD medium. Since you have this
with several media, probably the drive is going bad.

The message "mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0"
indicates that the DVD drive did not yet recognize
the medium when the system tried to mount it.
The fact that it sometimes works after some waiting
indicates that the drive needs a long time to inspect
the medium, if it succeeds at all.
Its unhealthy light show supports that theory.

Maybe there are some error messages in the system
log. You could execute command dmesg after the
problem happened next time.

You could use a burn program to watch the
SCSI command traffic and error replies.

```
xorriso -scsi_log on -outdev /dev/sr0
```

or

```
wodim -V dev=/dev/sr0 -inq
```

They will probably report error conditions like

```
START/STOP UNIT
1b 01 00 00 00 00 
+++ sense data = 70 00 02 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 3A 01 00 00 00 00
+++ key=2  asc=3Ah  ascq=01h
```

or

```
Executing 'test unit ready' command on Bus 0 Target 0, Lun 0 timeout 40s
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
Errno: 5 (Input/output error), test unit ready scsi sendcmd: no error
CDB:  00 00 00 00 00 00
status: 0x2 (CHECK CONDITION)
Sense Bytes: 70 00 02 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 3A 01 00 00
Sense Key: 0x2 Not Ready, Segment 0
Sense Code: 0x3A Qual 0x01 (medium not present - tray closed) Fru 0x0
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. It's a new drive - or rather an unused one from some years ago - which I installed to see if it would help, but it seems as bad. I coldn't see anything using dmesg but I will try out your suggestions

Comment: It was now reported that wodim reported an error
0x4 0x09 0x01 Hardware Error, tracking servo failure.
Installing a new DVD drive solved the problem.
The error code stems from the old drive. No problem with
operating system or ISO 9660 filesystem was involved.